# Speed up Trigger/Delay Actions Workflow in Animation Nodes

Tags: scripting, animation-nodes

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uv8FzbaxAw0&list=PLzx5ZMG3gsG8zvLGtVa7oecpu0DLygoqt) Thinking Penguin YouTube tutorial, we are shown the workflow for triggering the actions of a mesh matrix instances. The essential steps of this workflow are:

1. Animate some mesh object, *Orginal.Mesh.Object*
2. Export *Orginal.Mesh.Object* as .mdd
3. Duplicate *Orginal.Mesh.Object*, creating *Duplicate.Mesh.Object*
4. Apply Mesh Cache modifier to *Duplicate.Mesh.Object*, set file path to the .mdd you just exported
5. Set Mesh Cache modifier Time Mapping from *Scene* to *Custom*
6. Set start/end keyframes for Mesh Cache  *Evaluation Frame*
7. Use some kind of AN setup to instance *Duplicate.Mesh.Object* and control the actions of the instances (basic example pictured below)

Is there any way to automate some or all of these processes via a custom script? It's a very powerful node workflow but setting it up is tedious. 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your animations are already described parametrically so you needn't bake anything. Simply define a function that takes the time as input and outputs the required mesh. Then loop over your instances transformations and evaluate the function you created. A simple example would be as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Which results:

[image: Result]